# Church Online Platform Countdown Timer on Wix

Tags: javascript, velo

I'm having an issue making my countdown timer javascript work on my WIX site (camnaz.org). It should be pulling data from the Church Online Platform.  Our service on the Church Online Platform is camnaz.online.church.  I have inserted all the code into WIX and I have tried running the javascript on the WIX masterpage.js and on the page's javascript.

I think it's a lib document error.  My debugger is saying "Cannot find name 'document'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to include 'dom'."

Please help!!

```js
import "public/styles.css";
import "public/package.json"

const CURRENT_SERVICE_QUERY = `
query CurrentService {
  currentService(onEmpty: LOAD_NEXT) {
    id
    startTime
    endTime
    content {
      title
    }
  }
}
`;

async function startCountdown() {
  // Fetch the current or next service data
  const service = await fetch("https://camnaz.online.church/graphql", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Accept: "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: CURRENT_SERVICE_QUERY,
      operationName: "CurrentService"
    })
  })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));

  // If no service was returned from the API, don't display the countdown
  if (!service.data.currentService || !service.data.currentService.id) {
    return;
  }

  // Set the service title
  document.getElementById("serviceTitle").innerText =
    service.data.currentService.content.title;

  // Set the date we're counting down to
  const startTime = new Date(service.data.currentService.startTime).getTime();
  const endTime = new Date(service.data.currentService.endTime).getTime();

  // Create a one second interval to tick down to the startTime
  const intervalId = setInterval(function () {
    const now = new Date().getTime();

    // If we are between the start and end time, the service is live
    if (now >= startTime && now <= endTime) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Live";
      return;
    }

    // Find the difference between now and the start time
    const difference = startTime - now;

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    const days = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor(
      (difference % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
    );
    const minutes = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((difference % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Display the results in the element with id="countdown"
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML =
      days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    // If we are past the end time, clear the countdown
    if (difference < 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

startCountdown();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Countdown Example</title>
    <meta charset="Avenir" />
  </head>

  <body>
    NEXT ONLINE SERVICE:
    <div id="countdown"></div>
    <p id="serviceTitle"></p>

    <script src="src/CHOP.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What transpiler / debugger are you using?

Comment: I don't know anything about wix. If you don't know, or can't change the transpiler settings, try adding `if (!document) var document = {}` to the very top of your script. (this is a bit of a hack only use it if wix won't let you at the transpiler settings)

Comment: From the perspective of a German-speaker, the company could hardly have chosen a worse name.

Comment: I attempted the "hack" to no avail.  The debugger in WIX is it's one debugging tool.  You load your code in the masterPage.js code and run the script.

Answer (score 1):

`document` is not supported by Wix Velo as you do not have access to DOM, you need to use the [$w function](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/$w).

For example if I have a [text element](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/text) on the page with the id `text1` and I want to set the text to be `356` I will do the following:

```
$w("#text1").text = '356';
```

Or

```
const value = '356';
$w("#text1").text = value;
```

Also, I'm not sure what you are trying to do with these:

```
import "public/styles.css";
import "public/package.json"
```

You cannot use CSS on a Wix Site. Only limited use is available via the [.html](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/text/html) property of text elements and [.style](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/button/style) of some other elements.

Also, you cannot insert HTML tags on Wix. HTML code has to be embedded inside a [HTML component](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/$w/htmlcomponent). Read the [API reference](https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/) to understand more about Wix Velo as its different from traditional HTML, CSS, JS usage.

Comment: I know nothing about WIX, but if what you're stating is true it sounds like a real pain-in-the-ass experience for people with technical know-how.

Comment: @connexo I agree with you but its a give and take, you give up features, functions in order to get the ease of a visual editor combined with an IDE. Its a platform that can cater to a specific market, you cannot build enterprise level applications on it.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I swapped out my document.GetElementByID for $w and now I'm getting this error... "'serviceTitle' is not a valid selector. Capitalize the element type name without the hash symbol (#) (e.g. "Button") to select multiple elements."